# How to get property from ofono

Tags: c++, linux, dbus

I have made a program with C++ to get Properties of ofono API:

```
string Protocol [readwrite]

            Holds the protocol for this context.  Valid values
            are: "ip", "ipv6" and "dual".

        string Name [readwrite]

            The name is a free form string that describes this
            context.  The name should not be empty and limited
            to a short string for display purposes.

        dict Settings [readonly, optional]

            Holds all the IP network settings

            string Interface [readonly, optional]

                Holds the interface of the network interface
                used by this context (e.g. "ppp0" "usb0")

            string Method [readonly, optional]

                Holds the IP network config method
                    "static"- Set IP network statically
                    "dhcp"  - Set IP network through DHCP

            string Address [readonly, optional]
```

While I parse properties I use

```
...
for (auto p:prop){
p.first //to get name of property
p.second.reader().get_string() //to get string value of property
p.second.reader().get_bool() //to get boolean value of property
...
}
```

My problem is how to get names and values for dict type? like for example for `dict Settings [readonly, optional]` how to get `string Interface [readonly, optional]` or  `string Method [readonly, optional]`

Comment: can I transform dict to array or struct for getting values?

Comment: someone have an idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just I made this:

**p is element of prop defined in my question**

```
...
    DBus::MessageIter iterator = p.second.reader();
    std::map< std::string, ::DBus::Variant > mapping;
    iterator >> mapping;
    for (auto map:mapping) {
            map.first// contain the name 
            map.second.reader().get_string() // contain the string value
    }
...
```